# Can I get the exact click location relative to the element being clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element (a div) that is 100px wide and 30px high. I would like to calculate where on this element did the user click. For example if the click right in the middle of it I would like to get 50 for x coordinate and 15 for y coordinate. The values returned need to be relative to the element itself not the page or the parent.

Is this doable with JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: `HTML`  

    <div id="something" style="width: 100px; height:30px; border:1px solid red"></div>  
`script`  

    $("#something").click(function(e){
       var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
       //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
       var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
       var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
        alert('relX: '+ relX + ' ,relY: '+ relY);
    });  
>**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7o2849fq/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event which is passed to the jQuery handler contains the co-ordinates of the click event relevant to the parent DOMElement within the `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties. Try this:

```
$('#foo').click(function (e){
    console.log(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmze832k/)